# How to prove this "paint" riddle?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing, puzzle

$n\gt 2$ paint cans of identical shape and volume are filled with different type of paints. Each of them is filled with $\frac {n-1}{n}$ of their volume. It's allowed to fill the paint of one can to the other can.

> Prove that one can fill each can with paint such that in each can there is the same mixture.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Please explain how you got to the telescoping sum

Comment: There $n\ gt 2$ cans so with the volume of each can I thought immediately about the telescop sum.

Comment: This reminds me of Hilbert's hotel

Comment: Have you tried with $n = 3$, and seen how that went? Also, note that each can is filled with the same amount of paint. It's only if you get another bucket that you change the volume in each one.

Comment: Please state more clearly in the question the volume of the new can and its use

Comment: This is the task I got. I don't know how to clarify it better.

Comment: If you can't prove that this can be done for $n = 3$, you have little hope of being able to do it for general $n$. On the other hand, if you _can_ do it for $n = 3$, then you might be able to pick up a pattern that does generalise.

Comment: Is there no other way of proving this without induction?

Comment: I never said "use induction", although that definitely would work (why don't you want to use induction?) Focus on $3$ first, then after that see if you can do it in general without induction or if you need induction, or if you are still stuck. Say you have one can $2/3$ full of red paint, one can $2/3$ full of green paint and one can $2/3$ full of blue paint, and you want to end up with the same mixture in all of them. How would you do it?

Comment: (Also as a side note, "without induction" is probably impossible to truly achieve, since the natural numbers _by definition_ are constructed using induction, and the ability to use induction is perhaps the most characterising single feature of the natural numbers. You might be able to get away with no _explicit_ induciton written out in your proof, but it will always be there, lurking in the background.)

Comment: First pour the first one into the other two. Then pour it back in to the first one since one knew the measurements of 2nd and the 3rd. Then I'd be pour the the 2nd into the 3rd and then back.

Comment: Is pouring allowed only according to the Die Hard 2 rules (pour from A to B until A is empty or B is full, whatever happens first)? Or can we pour any amount between these exteremes (e.g., until A or B reaches a specific fill volume)?

Comment: I think the latter is allowed too.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen The Die Hard 3 rules (which is what I aassume you meant) were there only because they needed exact measurements, and you can't eyeball 4 gallons. That being said, having a measuring cup of some sort would help immensely.

Comment: Well there is nothing in the question that says so.

Comment: @Arthur Good catch - 2 was with the airport ... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pour from can $n$ into each other cans until they are full (and can $n$ is empty) and stir thoroughly. Now each can has the correct proportion of colour $n$, and this remains true no matter what we do from now on.

Next fill $\frac1n$ of each can into the $n$th can (apparently, this is an allowed step). Now we have the correct final mix in the $n$th can.
Each of the other $n-1$ cans is $\frac{n-2}{n-1}=1-\frac1{n-1}$ full so that we have reduced the problem to the case $n-1$.

Ultimately, the case $n=1$ is trivial.

Comment: There is no n=1 case. It starts from n=3.

Comment: @AnonymousI In order to show that something is true for $n\ge 3$, it is sufficient to show it is true for $n\ge 1$.

Comment: And what if the allowed step I presumed correct isn't allowed? Do you need to  make a can the same volume of the nth can so that you can pour it into the last can in the process?

Answer (score 1):

If we are allowed a measuring implement, then this is the method I thought of. The difference form Hagen's is that he empties the last can, then fills it up, then takes care of all the other cans, while I first fill up the last can, then take care of all the others, then empty the last can. It might be interesting to look into why one can swap the order around like this and still get it correctly.

> If there is only one can, there is no paint in it to mix, so in this case, mission accomplished, you are done. Otherwise take $\frac{1}{n(n-1)}$ from each of the other cans into the last one. The last one is now full, while all the others are $\frac{n-2}{n-1}$ full. Mix the others by the method described in this very paragraph, but for $n$ one smaller, so that they are all the same. Stir the last bucket, then fill all the other buckets with that paint, so that they get the same amount of paint each from the last bucket, and stir all the other buckets.